# .animate() STOPS working after a couple of times?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Okay, I have this sample from my code:

```
this.el.show().css({ "width" : 0 });
this.el.find('.mosaic-content-wrap').css({ "margin-left" : -this.width });

this.el.animate({ "width" : this.width }, duration);
this.el.find('.mosaic-content-wrap').animate({ "margin-left" : 0 }, duration);
```

All objects are fine, I tried logging all of them (including: this.el, this.width, this.el.find('.mosaic-content-wrap')

However, the .css() function is working and .animate() is just stops after a couple of times. I need to emphasize that - it works a couple of times and THEN stops working.

Can anyone think of any reason why .animate() would not work? Can I perform some test or something to find out what's wrong? I can't think of anything else than checking if "this.el" exists, and it does point to the correct element.

The full example can be seen here:
http://www.nikolaydyankov.com/Dev/mosaic
Try playing with the transition in order to brake it. It shouldn't take more than 2-3 times before it breaks.

Comment: The example you linked is working without any problems. I'm using Firefox 9.0.1.

Comment: Sorry, wrong comment. When I wrote the comment the pictures disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

Line 171 in *jquery.mosaic.slider.js* seems to be responsible, not `.animate()` but `.fadeIn()`:

```
this.el.fadeIn(duration);
```

This line is executed in order to show the mosaic pieces. After some while it's not executed anymore. I haven't figured out why this line is ignored after some while. But Firebug and it's Javascript debugger might help. Set a breakpoint to the line and try to figure out what happend.

Comment: Can't be fadeIn(), it's in an if statement and is executed only when the action is set to fade. If the action is "move..." only the snippet in my question is executed.

Comment: @NikolayDyankov Ah sorry! I was testing with *fade*, but it seems to be excactly the same problem. I don't think animate() is the real source of the problem.